# Apache cloudstack : host is not getting added, cloudstack-agent not active

Tags: cloud, agent, apache-cloudstack

I have implementation of cloudstack on virtual machine ubuntu 20, one NAT adapter active, cloudbr0 bridged to adapter. NExt task is to add zone, pod, cluster and host.
While adding host I am getting multiple errors. Upon log verification I found cloudstack-agent is still in activating state. Final reason is GUID not found hence no host getting created.
It is to note that KVM and Management server are configured on same host.

If anyone has answer to this please help.

Secondly Can someone please clarify
While creating host
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djKwJ.png)
here what should be host name.... should it be ip address of my virtual machine where bridging is done?
Also what will be username and password?
Will they be of the virtual machine or will that be something else?

Installed using Management server installation from official documentation